# Problems translating ASCII dec to character

Tags: c++, for-loop, arduino

Inside this function, I want the user to able to choose how many times he/her wants to repeat a test. I translate the ASCII dec (from `serial.read`), with char(incomingByte), but as soon as I enter the for-loop the number is changed back to its dec value... Can you explain why?

```
Serial.println("Choose number of times (max 10) to repeat test : ");
  while(Serial.available() == 0) {
    delay(10); 
  }
  int incomingByte = Serial.read();
  // Number of times to repeat test chosen by user.
  nRepeat = char(incomingByte);
  Serial.print("You chose : ");
  Serial.println(char(nRepeat));
  for(int i=0; i<nRepeat; i++) {
    randomSeed(A1);
    // Assigning a random seed for the random function.
    timer = random(2000, 5000);
    // Sets the random timer to vary between 2000 and 5000 ms
    delay(timer);
    // The delay is now random between 2000 and 5000 ms
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    // Turn on the LED (pin 13) 
    startTid = millis();
    // Saves the current time the Arduino has been powered.
    while(digitalRead(Buttom) == HIGH) {
      // Loop until buttom is pressed
    }
    stopTid = millis();
    // Saves current time since arduino got powered
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    // Turns LED off
    Serial.print("Your time was: ");    
    Serial.print(stopTid-startTid);
    // Prints the time between the exercise started and finished
    Serial.println(" milli seconds");
    person[cc].reacTime[i] = stopTid-startTid;
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(" out of ");
    Serial.println(nRepeat);
    delay(1000);                                        
  }
```

Comment: what do you think `char(nRepeat)` is doing, it's not a function for ascii translation, it's a function style c++ cast.

Comment: I assumed, that because I was declaring nRepeat = char(53) which gave me nRepeat = 5, that I could use this method to further use in for loops as an integer of ex. 5. Know a solution to this?

Comment: It actually depends on how you print it, if `.print()` method supports `%c` specifier, then may be `Serial.print("%c", nRepeat);` will do it, but I don't know the `Serial` class you are using.

Comment: looks like this is an Arduino library,  if so using `char incomingByte` eliminates the need for the cast looking at this example: http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/KeyboardSerial

Comment: ASCII 53 happens to be the character '5'

Answer (score 0):

As @iharob has pointed out, char() in C is not a function for translation.  The easiest way in C to do the ASCII transformation you are looking for is to subtract '0' from the entered value.  This relies on the fact that the numbers are in order in the ASCII table.  However, you will want to ensure that the user's input is actually a digit.  Your code will also only allow repeats from 0-9.

```
nRepeat = incomingByte - '0';
if (nRepeat >= 0 && nRepeat <= 9) {
    // Valid digit entered, proceed
    //...
}
```

Comment: Problem solved, I wrote a longer code with switch case defining nRepeat to be equal 1 when user typed 1, etc. to solve the problem if user typed something outside 0-10. Thanks for input

Answer (score 0):

When you `Serial.read()` you get the ASCII value of the number written by the user, i.e. `0 (zero) = 49`.
If you want to get the `int` value of the numbers written, you can use `Serial.parseInt()`. You can then make a `if` statement to make sure the number is between 0 and 10.

More documentation about `Serial.parseInt()` : http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/ParseInt